# Can I expand downloading images to several threads?

Tags: c#, multithreading, silverlight, windows-phone-7

I had a problem with `ListBox`, which doesn't work fine with my collection (nested listboxes, non static size, etc). I tried [DeferredLoadListBox](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/delay/archive/2010/09/08/never-do-today-what-you-can-put-off-till-tomorrow-deferredloadlistbox-and-stackpanel-help-windows-phone-7-lists-scroll-smoothly-and-consistently.aspx), but it requires static height(not my variant).

So, I tried `ItemsControl` with `ScrollViewer`, and it works realy good! I have smooth scrolling, no lags, its exactly what i needed. But! As I understand, `ListBox` download content dynamically, only when it need this content, and `ItemsControl` loads all the content in one time.

And its a problem, because I load in `ItemsControl` a collection of 40-50 items, and each item has 1-4 images, and it takes about 5-6 seconds(than `ItemsControl` works great). As I understand - in this 5-6 seconds it downloads all the images. **Question** - is there any way to expand this operation to several threads, and using this hint reduce the `ItemsControl's` freezing?

Comment: Why are you downloading 40-50 items into a UI list?  I would question putting that many items into a list in the first place, but even if you want to keep that structure, you should work on only fetching the items that are visible, plus maybe a couple in the up and down direction to allow smoother scrolling.  Think of the way Facebook's pages works.  They don't load the entire feed at once, they load it as you scroll and need more information.

Comment: Because, if i use `ListBox` (which have logic you wrote) - I have laggs, no smooth scrolling, etc. It's because of that each item has its own size, some of them have nested ListBox'es and more. See [link](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/slmperf/archive/2010/10/06/silverlight-for-windows-phone-7-listbox-scroll-performance.aspx)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use [LowProfileImageLoader](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/delay/archive/2010/09/02/keep-a-low-profile-lowprofileimageloader-helps-the-windows-phone-7-ui-thread-stay-responsive-by-loading-images-in-the-background.aspx) with the standard ListBox

Comment: Tried, it requires static height of item. My content have different size for every item

Comment: @eg01st no it does not, just the DefferedLoadListBox does. Use the standard Listbox without item height definition plus the LowProfileImageLoader

Comment: Thanks! I didn't attentioned this.